# How to write html tags without triggering the page

Tags: html

I am trying to be able to show the code `<code><div class="classname"></div></code>` to the user but instead of writing out what I wrote between the code tag it actually does make the page thing im genuinely trying to make a div box so is there anyway to avoid it?

Comment: What code are you executing? What's the "page thing"?

Comment: Im not trying to execute <code><div class="classname"></div></code> im trying to do the opposite where it show the on the page instead of executing.